# ASP.NET MVC4 @Html.ListBoxFor Multiple to DB using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, selection

Hi I am still new to MVC4, I would like to use HTML helper to create a select box that would allow users to select multiple items using CTRL Click and store results using EF. Here is my view

```
@model AtomicQuestionnaire.Models.Questionnaire

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@{
    var ListInterest = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
new SelectListItem(){Value="Stamp Collecting",Text="Stamp Collecting"},
new SelectListItem(){Value="Listening to Music",Text="Listening to Music"},
new SelectListItem(){Value="Reading",Text="Reading"}
};




}

<h2>Create</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interest)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Interest, ListInterest, new { size = "15", Multiple = "multiple" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interest)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here is my model

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string VisitorDesc { get; set; }
    public string Interest { get; set; }
    public int SiteRating { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller for create action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Questionnaire questionnaire)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Questionnaires.Add(questionnaire);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(questionnaire);
}
```

I was only able to store the first item of the html selection box to database. Would you be able to tell me what I did wrong? I would like to store all selected items into DB. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be a collection of Questionnaires you handle, and not just a single object?

Comment: Any recommendation/correction is appreciated as I am still new to .Net world. Thanks.

Comment: Try checking out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104110/multiple-selection-of-listbox-is-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc4?rq=1 to see if it sheds some light :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to select multiple listbox values you have to define your model's property as

`public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }`,

not as

```
public string Interest { get; set; }
```

If `Interests` property is collection, you will need a separate table to store them (separate entity at the EF level).

```
public class Interest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Questionnaire> Questionnaires { get; set; }
}
```

For there entities EF will generate `Interests` table and a junction table to store Questionnaire-Interest associations.

The view:

```
@{
    var ListInterest = new List<SelectListItem>() //hard-code, better load interests from db
{
new SelectListItem(){ Value = 1, Text="Stamp Collecting" },
new SelectListItem(){ Value=2, Text="Listening to Music" },
new SelectListItem(){ Value=3, Text="Reading"}
}; 

Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.Interests,
                new MultiSelectList(ListInteres, "Value", "Text"))
```

Notice, that Interest Entities must exist in db (or `SaveChanges` will raise an exception). You can add them manually for now or write a separate add/edit page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that but none of the listbox values were stored. I removed the connections and the db file from app-data and rebuilt. And found out that the DB column Interest was not created at all.

Comment: My bad, forgot about db. Collection properties cannot be stored in a single column, you need a separate table for them. Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks again. How should I update the view appropriately from the following. Sorry for noobish question

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Interest, ListInterest)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interest)
        </div>

Comment: Also for the sake of simplicity, is there any way to just concat all the selected options as one string and store in a string field instead of a collection? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, you can do the following:

1) Declare `ICollection<string>` property in the model. It will not be saved (cause EF does not save collections in single column), but still will be bound.
   But then you will need one more property to store concatenated values and pass it to db. (Smth like `model.InterestsConcatenated = string.Join(",", Model.Interests);`)
   Or, you can separate the domain model from the view model.

2) Grab values directly from `Request.Form` and concatenate them to a single string.

Comment: Error: The value '1,2,3' is invalid. 

I appreciate your quick responses. I will try to figure it myself using the concat method instead. Thanks